# Preview randomly unable to display certain documents

Tags: preview

On the MBA of a friend (10.10.3) when I double click on `PDF` or `JPG` files to open them with `Preview`, the app opens but the file does not display 90% of the time. If I press <kbd>Space</kbd> the document displays fine in `quicklook`.

#### What I've done:

- Looked on the `Console` => no message on it
- Fixed permissions => no change.

I'd *love* to **not** re-install the system to fix the issue, is there anything I could try to open the document normally?

Comment: What error message do you get when double clicking on PDF and JPEG files? Is it only those that don't display correctly the majority of the time?

Comment: @mjturner I don't get error message, it just doesn't open the file. I only tried with PDF & JPEG because that's my main use.

Comment: &Thomas Can you try exiting Preview.app and seeing if that helps? It's odd that you don't at least get an error message. Are the files on a network drive or are they local (not that it should make a difference...)?

Comment: @mjturner once it start bugging there is no way back, no matter how many times I close the app. The files are local and I can open its without problem on my own mac